# install mathtime package in texlive

Tags: packages, texlive, mathtime

I need to use the `mathtime` package with the option `cmbold`:

```
\usepackage[cmbold]{mathtime}
```

MiKTeX database actually identifies `mathtime` as a regular package and automatically updates and install. But, in TeX live database such a package name is not recognized. What is the equivalent name there?

Comment: From [CTAN Catalogue entry `psnfssx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/psnfssx): "The Mi­cro­press fonts, Lu­cida, Math­time and the Euro­pean Modern fonts are not them­selves avail­able free". TeX Live AFAIK does not have packages for non-free fonts. There are alternatives like [`belleek`](https://ctan.org/pkg/belleek). But I never used one of them.

Comment: The problem is not with a missing font. I already installed "belleek" family. The problem is using such fonts via a missing package in texlive; this package is called "mathtime" by miktex

Comment: Nevertheless: The package is part of `psnfssx` and `psnfssx` is not available as TeX Live package (because it depends on non-free fonts). So if you want to use this package you have to install it manually.

Comment: I couldn't actually find it under "psnfssx". Here is the list of packages "psnfssx" provides: mathpazo , mathptmx , helvet , avant , courier , chancery , bookman , newcent , charter

Comment: Try the link in my first comment and you will find, e.g. [folder `mathtime`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/mathtime) with `mathtime.dtx` and [`mathtime.ins`](https://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/mathtime/mathtime.ins). The last one has a line `\generateFile{mathtime.sty}{f}{\from{mathtime.dtx}{package,mathtime}}`. So you are wrong again: `psnfssx` does have `mathtime.sty`.

Comment: `latex mathtime.ins` `latex mathtime.dtx` I got. `mathpi.sty    mathtime.ins  mathtime.txt  my2mtt.fd     umh2scr.fd
mathtime.aux  mathtime.log  mh2scr.enc    my3mtt.fd     umh6.fd
mathtime.dtx  mathtime.pdf  mtfonts.fdd   omslby.fd     umtms.fd
mathtime.dvi  mathtime.sty  my1mtt.fd     umh2.fd` How to install manually? @Schweinebacke It could be helpful if you write the steps as an anwser.